# Action on segment click in Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

In the new version of Xcode don't see any way to start IBAction when the segment is clicked.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: I want a segmentedControl to be connected to a IBAction that will be activated then the user clicks on the segmentedControl.

Comment: Then in interface builder, command click from your segmented control into your header file to create an IBAction.

Comment: The error was something else, sorry... Many many thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I will put you in the credits when the application is finished :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

i just connected the segmentedControl to the IBAction as it was. The reason that it didn't work was that the thing that was giving error was actually some code inside the IBAction and not the link between the segment and the IBAction. Stupid me...

Sometimes you just don't see you own stupid errors :-(

Anyway many many thanks to David for trying to help :-)